# What is the type of a commonjs module imported into a typescript file?

Tags: typescript, import, typescript-typings, commonjs

I am importing a CommonJS module in a Typescript source. As a result I receive an object containing exported features of the module.

In my concrete use case the declarations for NodeJS's `fs` module declare the exports as (typescript-) module, not as type. I need an interface declaration for that module, so that I can pass the module object without loosing the type information or to extend the module.

Here is what I want to do:

```js
import * as fs from "fs";

doSomethingWithFs(fsParameter: InstanceType<fs>) {
    ...
}
```

This results in

```
TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'fs' as a type.
```

Is there any way to get a type from a module declaration (other than manually refactoring the typings)?

**EDIT**:
@Skovy's solution works perfectly:

```js
import * as fs from "fs";

export type IFS = typeof fs;

// IFS can now be used as if it were declared as interface:
export interface A extends IFS { ... }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `typeof`?

```js
import * as fs from "fs";

function doSomethingWithFs(fsParameter: typeof fs) {
  fsParameter.readFile(...);
}
```

Comment: Well no, I didn't. I assumed `typeof fs === "object"`.

What is `typeof fs`? It actually does most of what I need it to do, with the exception that `interface X extends typeof fs { ... }` does not work (that's part of the something in my code sniplet).

Comment: The second part also works if instead of `...extends typeof fs` I declare a type alias for `fs`, updated the question. Thanks @Skovy, that really helped ;-)